# How to store 2D Array coordinates in a list in java

Tags: java, arrays, list

Question is kind of hard to ask. I'll try my best to explain it.

I have a 2D array that is a grid. This grid has its contents filled with 0 and 1.

I want to store in a list the coordinates of the array that only have 0. How would you do that?

For example: the coordinate location 2, 3 has the value of 0. How should one go about storing the 2, 3?

Comment: by "list" do you mean a java.util.List, or a one-dimensional array?

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx Would the answer be different either way?

Comment: just trying to get a clearer question. and yes, slightly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a `Point` class that has coordinates (x,y) and the value 0 or 1.  Store a `List<Point>` and you're all set.

Comment: THANK YOU, wow I feel stupid. I've been using point all this time and didn't realize I should do it that way...

Comment: As a side note, I find that having a `Map<Point,SomeValue>` works a lot better than a `SomeValue[]`. Three reasons: 1) Separation from 0. 2) Negative coords. 3) Non-rectangular grids (Think shaped like Utah) don't waste tons of space.

Comment: @abc123  If duffymo's reply answered your question, please mark it correct.