# How to store 2D Array coordinates in a list (not using list container?)

Tags: java, arrays

Firstly I did my homework,
I've checked this:
[How to store 2D Array coordinates in a list in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697722/how-to-store-2d-array-coordinates-in-a-list-in-java)

I have created my own Vector2 class (like XNA).
I think if i use list and access the list every frame, it might slow my game down:S

I need to access this array every frame, so I really want to know if i can create them in a high efficiency way (not using list or class,just some basic type like int[]).

thx in advance!

Edit:
just access this array(the array will be created on init), because i need to search this array's element every frame in my game. I did want to try Vector2[]..  buy the efficiency y'konw ^^

Edit*2:eh,I'm really new to JAVA. the "map" you mean use map to store Vector2?

Comment: Well, try it first, and see if it actually causes a performance problem. If it doesn't (in comparison to some other method you come up with) then don't worry about it. Trying to solve a problem that doesn't yet exist is not a good use of your time. http://agilesoftwaredevelopment.com/blog/pbielicki/premature-optimization-root-all-evil-not-only-agile-world  Also, if it turns out you're right (that it's slow) you'll learn a lot more about *why* and how to do it differently in the future if you let it fail first.

Comment: Do you want to create or access this array in every frame? What kind of access do you need (full, random, lifo, )? Expanding on these matters is likely to get the question a better answer.

Comment: What efficiency issue do you believe you'll have with an array of Vector2? If you need a collection of Vector2, and need constant access time to arbitrary elements, and don't want them in a map, what do you believe will be faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, arrays are (mostly) objects.  That is why you can do stuff like

```
int[] b = { 2, 4, 5 };
System.out.println(b.length);
```

I know you are concerned with speed; however, attempting to program in a non-object-oriented manner in Java doesn't speed up your program.  The JVM is optimized heavily to make object-oriented code run fast.

Concentrate more on your algorithms.  If you can keep a list of "to be updated" items instead of iterating over a list of all items, you will dramatically speed up your program regardless of the data structure.  Only go shopping for better implementations of data structures after you have determined that the data structure is the slow part.

Premature optimization means you start writing your code to be fast (which normally means you make large concessions to reduce readability) before you have determined that the section of code is impacting the speed of your program.  You don't want to make a section of critical code unreadable before you realize it's only 5% of the problem that is making your code slow.

[Semi-recent benchmarking puts a correctly sized ArrayList within 3% of the speed of a raw array](http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/testing/index-2.html).  If you are wrapping your raw array in an object, odds are good the stock implementation of the ArrayList around its embedded array is much faster.

Comment: great! as you said that i really should take care of my algorithms.